# loginButton.setFragment(this); crashes app

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

I'm trying to make an app that simply logs into facebook and then logs out. My app would compile and load however adding the line: `loginButton.setFragment(this)` causes a compilation which I have fixed by using the package `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` rather than `android.app.Fragment`. The issue is that now my app crashes whenever I try to run it.

This is my MainFragment.java

```
//MainFragment.java
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;
    private TextView mTextDetails;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile != null){
                mTextDetails.setText("Welcome" + profile.getName());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallBackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends", "user_photos");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, mCallBack);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample" >



    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my MainFragment layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/text_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the logcat

```
   --------- beginning of crash
07-25 05:12:55.211    2473-2473/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample, PID: 2473
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4529)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4529)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.stan.facebooktestexactexample.MyApplication
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Please Help!!

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: i have posted it @Lal

Answer (score 0):

if you set android:name=".MyApplication" on manifest you have to create MyApplication class.If you dont want that remove it or create class as

```
public class MyAppilcation extends Application{
...
}
```

it is used to declare global variables.

see this link [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)